# Resize of external SWF exported from Unity3d

Tags: actionscript-3, air, unity-game-engine

I exported a swf using Unity3D 3.5 preview.

I can not change the dimensions when I load in as3 (Adobe Air 3).

When the swf loads appears the logo of unity with loading, that resizes to 730x750! Great ok! But when the loader of unity ends the swf resize for the stage size (1920x1080). =/

I set the resolution to 730x750 in Unity3D.

Any ideas? Tks!

My code in as3:

```
    public function mc_produto_swf() 
    {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Sapato_01.swf");
        loader.load(url);
    }

    public function loaderComplete(event:Event):void
    { 
        var cont:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.currentTarget.content);
        cont.width = 730;
        cont.height = 750;

        this.addChild( cont );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the same question in the Unity3d forums and the user "UnityRalph" help me:

> Our content isn't really a resizable display object as it uses Stage3D (we probably could make it take displaylist width, height, x, y, though, thinking about it). 
>   
> For now what you can do is UnityShared.swc: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/116650-UnityShared.swc-Communicating-between-Unity-Flash-Content-and-AS3
>   
> The loader you can use from the swc allows specification of size and stage to size or not.

Works for me, but i tried change the position x and not work.